# TypeError: checkForNode8 is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I get `TypeError: checkForNode8 is not a function` when I try to run firebase deploy to deploy my cloud functions on a new project. I am not new to cloud functions, it works on my older projects but new projects get this error. I have tried updating npm updating firebase tools, reinstalling them, everything I can think of. I can't seem to find anything thing on this error on google.
I have been at this for hours. Any help would be much appreciated. This is a snippet of the debug log:

```
...
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'woop-5c6c3'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying functions 
[info] Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
[info] ✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script. 
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:38:25.931Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
[info] i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... 
[info] i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled... 
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:38:27.300Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/woop-5c6c3/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com  
...
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:39:33.357Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 16 Dec 2020 06:39:33 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[info] ✔  functions[newDriverRequest(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.  
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:39:33.537Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 16 Dec 2020 06:39:33 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:39:35.543Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/d29vcC01YzZjMy91cy1jZW50cmFsMS91cGRhdGVEcml2ZXJSZXF1ZXN0L3hPcTlvNVJ5YzRV  
 
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:39:36.021Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 16 Dec 2020 06:39:36 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[info] ✔  functions[updateDriverRequest(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.  
[debug] [2020-12-16T06:39:36.026Z] TypeError: checkForNode8 is not a function
    at _fetchTriggerUrls.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release.js:413:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the CLI that was fixed in [v9.0.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.0.1) -- just update to the latest version and you should be good to go.